# Giving Each Question Its Own Code Repository

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, reputation

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3841231/119895) some days ago in stackoverflow that involves generating a custom widget for android.

I just edited my answer adding some code I did so far and I used someone else code as well.
I didn't paste it all in the question because I didn't want to use all the space with code.

I was willing to place the code somewhere people can edit or propose patches.

So that's why I would like to have this.
Each question having a repo (svn/git/whatever) where people can upload code and get improved by the community.

What do you think?

PS: Accepted patches == rep points? :)

Comment: I think this is an interesting idea, but we have lots of other sites that act as code repositories already.

Answer (score 3):

If it is more a development project than a question, than it's probably not a good fit for a Q&A site. I think Stack Overflow should stick to Q&A.

Comment: Then should my question be closed for subjective and argumentative?

Answer (score 0):

The stackexchange network is growing to support Q&A not only for programming, and this wouldn't be useful on them.

So I disagree